# How do I cross reference an equation in lstlisting?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, labels

Suppose we have the following code:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
f(x)=x+2
\end{equation}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica, basicstyle=\scriptsize] 
f[x_]:=f[x]=x+2 (* See \ref{eq:1} *)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

However, `\ref{eq:1}` in `lstlisting` clearly doesn't work.

How do we create a cross reference of `eq:1` in `lstlisting`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension `listings` provides several mechanisms for an escape to LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\lstset{escapeinside=||}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
f(x)=x+2
\end{equation}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica, basicstyle=\scriptsize] 
f[x_]:=f[x]=x+2 (* See |\ref{eq:1}| *)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above]